# Flexbox curved corners

Tags: css, flexbox

Is it possible to have the contents of a **flexbox adapt to it's border radius**.

For example:

If we have a flexbox with `border-radius: 10px` when we reorder the elements inside the box is it possible to have the resulting corner elements have the same respective border-radius.

ex:
    The top right element will have **border-top-right-radius: 10px**

Comment: @web-tiki please add your solution as an answer to this question, so OP can check it and we can close the question.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You just need to add `overflow:hidden;` to the parent element with the border-radius property.

**Explanation :**
The issue is that the flexbox items are overflowing the parent element and therefore, the border radius doesn't apply on the items.
To prevent them from overflowing their parent, you need to add `overflow:hidden;` to the parent `.wrap` in the following example :

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100px;
  background: teal;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.item:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why it is like this?

Comment: @BimalDas I have edited the answer with an explanation