# Change the border radius of the slider

Tags: css, elementor

I am trying to change the border radius of the slider on the website. I am not able to do it through elementor widget, column, or section styles. Can someone help me change the border-radius.

eleven46.eu is the website

[image]

Comment: Where exactly is that slider on the webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in this case is the usage of `flexbox`.

To fix the problem, you need to add following snippet to the custom CSS code of the column:

```
.elementor-element-ba1ea68 {
    border-radius: 25px; /*rounded corners*/
    overflow: hidden; /*flexbox fix*/
}
```

If you have Elementor Pro, omit the opening and closing line of the CSS code I provided. If you can't put the code in Elementor's CSS field, paste it in the Wordpress' custom CSS (*Appearance -> Editor* in the dashboard of your WP page)

*Answer based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27742550/12631978), originally posted by [web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811992/web-tiki)*